# convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x^3-x)\, dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

What can we say about the convergence of the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(x^3-x) dx$$
A related integral would be $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos x^3 \,dx$. Integrating by parts, it is easy to see that the integral converges. But I couldn't quite relate these two integrals. What are some general methods to try when posed with testing convergence of integrals? Another interesting question to consider might be to replace $x^3-x$ by any polynomials in $x$. What happens then?

Comment: You can still integrate by parts by writing the integrand as $(3 x^2-1)\cos(x^3-x)(3 x^2-1)^{-1}$ when $x\ge 1$ for example.

Comment: Wolframalpha shows that the integral converges and is equal to $$\frac{\pi\operatorname{Ai}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\approx1.11098$$ where $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$ is the Airy function

Comment: The alternating series test shows that $$\int_{a}^{\infty}\sin(xf(x))\, dx$$ converges for any $a\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ whenever $f(x)$ monotonically goes to $+\infty$. $f(x)=x^2-1+\frac{\pi}{2x}$ is such a function.

Comment: @Gribouillis With your idea and if my calculations are correct, the integral becomes
$\frac{\sin(x^3-x)}{3x^2-1}\vert_{1}^{\infty}+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{6x\sin(x^3-x)}{(3x^2-1)^2}$, and the later integral converges absolutely by comparison test. Is this correct?

Comment: @TakamotoYuji It is correct. You can generalize this to $\int \cos(P(x)) d x$ where $P$ is a polynomial and $\text{degree}(P)>1$